# Show a alert message when pressing button without exiting the modal form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I have a signup modal form and I want the users to get an alert message if there are fields empty when they press the register button.

I can't really figure it out how to do it.

As I said in my previous posts I am new to coding so please be patient with me.

Thank you!

```
<div class="modal fade" id="signUp" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

    <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h3 class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Registro</h3>

        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">

        <form action="" name="registerform" id="signup1" method="POST" role="form">
            <div class="row">

            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="name"><i class="fa fa-user-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Nombres</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Ingresa tu(s) nombre(s)">
                  <span id="nameerror" class="hidden form-error"><p> *Solo pueden ser letras</p> </span>
                </div>
            </div>  

            <div class="col-xs-6">  
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="lname"><i class="fa fa-user-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Apellidos</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Ingresa tus apellidos">
                  <span id="lnameerror" class="hidden form-error"><p> *Solo pueden ser letras</p> </span>
                </div>
            </div>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group" id="genero">

                <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">

                <label for="masculino" class="btn btn-default active">
                <input type="radio" name="genero" id="masculino" autocomplete="off" checked value="M">
                Masculino
                </label>

                <label for="femenino" class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" name="genero" id="femenino" autocomplete="off" value="F">
                Femenino
                </label>

                </div>
            </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="email"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Correo electronico</label><span id="resultmail"></span>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Ingresa tu correo electronico" autocomplete="off">
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="user"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> Usuario</label><span id="result"></span>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user" id="user" placeholder="Ingresa tu usuario" autocomplete="off">
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                  <label><i class="fa fa-birthday-cake" aria-hidden="true"></i> Fecha de nacimiento</label>

                    <div class="row" id="fecha">

                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <select class="form-control btn-default custom" name="day">

                                <option hidden>Dia</option>

                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                                <option value="4">4</option>
                                <option value="5">5</option>
                                <option value="6">6</option>
                                <option value="7">7</option>
                                <option value="8">8</option>
                                <option value="9">9</option>
                                <option value="10">10</option>
                                <option value="11">11</option>
                                <option value="12">12</option>
                                <option value="13">13</option>
                                <option value="14">14</option>
                                <option value="15">15</option>
                                <option value="16">16</option>
                                <option value="17">17</option>
                                <option value="18">18</option>
                                <option value="19">19</option>
                                <option value="20">20</option>
                                <option value="21">21</option>
                                <option value="22">22</option>
                                <option value="23">23</option>
                                <option value="24">24</option>
                                <option value="25">25</option>
                                <option value="26">26</option>
                                <option value="27">27</option>
                                <option value="28">28</option>
                                <option value="29">29</option>
                                <option value="30">30</option>
                                <option value="31">31</option>


                            </select>

                    </div>


                    <div class="col-xs-4">

                        <select class="form-control btn-default custom" name="month">

                                <option hidden>Mes</option>

                                <option value="01">Enero</option>
                                <option value="02">Febrero</option>
                                <option value="03">Marzo</option>
                                <option value="04">Abril</option>
                                <option value="05">Mayo</option>
                                <option value="06">Junio</option>
                                <option value="07">Julio</option>
                                <option value="08">Agosto</option>
                                <option value="09">Septiembre</option>
                                <option value="10">Octubre</option>
                                <option value="11">Noviembre</option>
                                <option value="12">Diciembre</option>

                            </select>

                        </div>


                    <div class="col-xs-4">

                        <select class="form-control btn-default custom" name="year">
                                <option hidden>Año</option>
                                <option value="2003">2003</option>
                                <option value="2002">2002</option>
                                <option value="2001">2001</option>
                                <option value="2000">2000</option>
                                <option value="1999">1999</option>
                                <option value="1998">1998</option>
                                <option value="1997">1997</option>
                                <option value="1996">1996</option>
                                <option value="1995">1995</option>
                                <option value="1994">1994</option>
                                <option value="1993">1993</option>
                                <option value="1992">1992</option>
                                <option value="1991">1991</option>
                                <option value="1990">1990</option>
                                <option value="1989">1989</option>
                                <option value="1988">1988</option>
                                <option value="1987">1987</option>
                                <option value="1986">1986</option>
                                <option value="1985">1985</option>
                                <option value="1984">1984</option>
                                <option value="1983">1983</option>
                                <option value="1982">1982</option>
                                <option value="1981">1981</option>
                                <option value="1980">1980</option>
                                <option value="1979">1979</option>
                                <option value="1978">1978</option>
                                <option value="1977">1977</option>
                                <option value="1976">1976</option>
                                <option value="1975">1975</option>
                                <option value="1974">1974</option>
                                <option value="1973">1973</option>
                                <option value="1972">1972</option>
                                <option value="1971">1971</option>
                                <option value="1970">1970</option>
                                <option value="1969">1969</option>
                                <option value="1968">1968</option>
                                <option value="1967">1967</option>
                                <option value="1966">1966</option>
                                <option value="1965">1965</option>
                                <option value="1964">1954</option>
                                <option value="1963">1963</option>
                                <option value="1962">1962</option>
                                <option value="1961">1961</option>
                                <option value="1960">1960</option>
                                <option value="1959">1959</option>
                                <option value="1958">1958</option>
                                <option value="1957">1957</option>
                                <option value="1956">1956</option>
                                <option value="1955">1955</option>
                                <option value="1954">1954</option>
                                <option value="1953">1953</option>
                                <option value="1952">1952</option>
                                <option value="1951">1951</option>
                                <option value="1950">1950</option>
                                <option value="1949">1949</option>
                                <option value="1948">1948</option>
                                <option value="1947">1947</option>
                                <option value="1946">1946</option>
                                <option value="1945">1945</option>
                                <option value="1944">1944</option>
                                <option value="1943">1943</option>
                                <option value="1942">1942</option>
                                <option value="1941">1941</option>
                                <option value="1940">1940</option>
                                <option value="1939">1939</option>
                                <option value="1938">1938</option>
                                <option value="1937">1937</option>
                                <option value="1936">1936</option>
                                <option value="1935">1935</option>
                                <option value="1934">1934</option>
                                <option value="1933">1933</option>
                                <option value="1932">1932</option>
                                <option value="1931">1931</option>
                                <option value="1930">1930</option>
                                <option value="1929">1929</option>
                                <option value="1928">1928</option>
                                <option value="1927">1927</option>
                                <option value="1926">1926</option>
                                <option value="1925">1925</option>
                                <option value="1924">1924</option>
                                <option value="1923">1923</option>
                                <option value="1922">1922</option>
                                <option value="1921">1921</option>
                                <option value="1920">1920</option>
                                <option value="1919">1919</option>
                                <option value="1918">1918</option>
                                <option value="1917">1917</option>
                                <option value="1916">1916</option>
                                <option value="1915">1915</option>
                                <option value="1914">1914</option>
                                <option value="1913">1913</option>
                                <option value="1912">1912</option>
                                <option value="1911">1911</option>
                                <option value="1910">1910</option>
                                <option value="1909">1909</option>
                                <option value="1908">1908</option>
                                <option value="1907">1907</option>
                                <option value="1906">1906</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="password"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Contrasena</label><span id="resultpass"></span>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Ingresa tu contrasena" autocomplete="off">
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="cpassword"><i class="fa fa-keyboard-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Confirma tu contrasena</label><span id="resultcpass"></span>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="cpassword" name="cpassword" placeholder="Vuelve a ingresar tu contrasena" autocomplete="off">

                </div>





        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">

            <input type="submit" id="btnregistrar" name="register" class="btn btn-default" value="Registrar"></input>

            <button type="button" id="btncerrar1" id="reset" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>


        </div>
</form>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Have a look at something like http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/simple.html

Comment: Already did but I don't really get the example. I kind of know the pseudocode which could be:

Comment: If button is pressed (If fields are not empty and fields do not have user-validation-w class then disable button and alert user.) else register user.